# Permission denied on executing .sh file from ant script

Tags: shell

I am trying to execute a shell script from the ant file but it is giving the error as: 
     [exec] /bin/sh: ./abc.sh: Permission denied
     [exec] Result: 126

My code snippet is:

```
<exec dir="." executable="/bin/sh">
                <arg line="-c './abc.sh -s ${arg1}'" />
        </exec>
```

Before executing the script, If I set the permission as below still I get the same error.

```
<chmod file="/abc.sh" perm="777"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. hope it helps

`<chmod file="shell-script-location" perm="g+w" type="file"/>`

you can either choose type="file" or "dir" or "both"